# Lifelog API totals not matching up

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

I have been able to retrieve data from the Lifelog API and calculate all of the totals I need, but I am finding that the totals I calculate are different than the one's the Lifelog app is showing. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Here is an example query I am running to get total steps:

```
/me/activities?start_time=2015-01-20T00:00:00.391-20&end_time=2015-01-20T23:59:00.000Z&type=physical:walk
```

Answer (score 0):

The full guide on how to calculate totals is now available here:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/guides/how-to-calculate-daily-totals/